# PrestaShop: unset a carrier from checkout page

Tags: php, prestashop

Hi i'm trying to unset a carrier from list of available carriers in checkout page (in step 2). I'm trying to unset it from a hook: hookDisplayBeforeCarrier, but carrier still remains. Is not a cache problem.

Many thanks!!

```
 public function hookDisplayBeforeCarrier($params)
{

    $delivery_option_list = $params['delivery_option_list'];

    foreach ($delivery_option_list as $id_address => $carrier_list_raw) {
        foreach ($carrier_list_raw as $key => $carrier_list) {
            foreach ($carrier_list['carrier_list'] as $id_carrier => $carrier) {
                if ($id_carrier != 21) {
                    continue;
                }
                unset($delivery_option_list[$id_address][$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->context->smarty->assign('delivery_option_list', $delivery_option_list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable a carrier it is in the backoffice via the page "carrier".

If it is for a particular product, you can activate or not carriers by product via the "delivery" tab of the product page.

Regards,

---

Hi,

Alternatively, assigned one carrier per customer group, and according to the needs assigned the user to one or more client groups, given it access or not to the carriers.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but i want to disable a carrier automatically, i'm developing a module....

Comment: Yes automatically in DB with your module ?